# How to call org.jdom.Element APIs using JNI C++

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

New to JNI. I am trying to call Element::getChild and Element::getChildText APIs (java org.jdom.Element) to get the version number of a system that is stored in "settings.xml" This xml file is archived in JAR file. Assuming the root element is available, here is what I am doing:

```
jstring fileNameStr = env->NewStringUTF("settings.xml");
jobject rootElement = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(a_class, xmlRootElement_mid, fileNameStr);

jclass cls_element = env->FindClass("org/jdom/Element");

/*get method ID for getChild() & getChildText() */
jmethodID getChild_mid = env->GetMethodID(cls_element, "getChild", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/jdom/Element;");
jmethodID getChildText_mid = env->GetMethodID(cls_element, "getChildText", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;");

jstring aboutStr = env->NewStringUTF("about");
jobject about = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(cls_element, getChild_mid, aboutStr); ---> Seg Faults!!!
```

Basically, I want to do Java equivalent of this:

```
In Java:
import org.jdom.Element;
...
Element element = SomeMethodToReadXmlFile("settings.xml");
version = element.getChild("about").getChildText("version");  <---- works
```

How should I do this?

Comment: Why are you using `CallStaticObjectMethod` and `cls_element`? Judging by your Java code, `getChild` is an instance method, not a class method.

Comment: @Michael Can you give example how this should be called?

Comment: For static methods: use `GetStaticMethodID`, and then `CallStatic<Type>Method` with a `jclass` as the first argument. For instance methods: use `GetMethodID`, and then `Call<Type>Method` with a `jobject` as the first argument.

Comment: @Michael - many thanks! Got it working. I will post answer - may help someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JNI, here is what worked for me that uses org.jdom.Element. My settings.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<settings>
  <about>
     <version>1.0</version>
  </about>
</settings>
```

JNI C++:

```
jstring fileNameStr = env->NewStringUTF("settings.xml");

// assuming xmlRootElement_mid is known
jobject element_obj = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(a_class, xmlRootElement_mid, fileNameStr);

jclass cls_element = env->FindClass("org/jdom/Element");

/*get method ID for getChild() & getChildText() */
jmethodID getChild_mid = env->GetMethodID(cls_element, "getChild", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/jdom/Element;");
jmethodID getChildText_mid = env->GetMethodID(cls_element, "getChildText", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;");

jstring jstr = env->NewStringUTF("about");
element_obj = env->CallObjectMethod(element_obj, getChild_mid, jstr)

jstr = env->NewStringUTF("version");
jstring version_str = (jstring)env->CallObjectMethod(element_obj, getChildText_mid, jstr);

//Convert to std::string
std::string version_std_str;
if (version_str)
{
   const char *c = env->GetStringUTFChars(version_str, 0);
   version_std_str = std::string(c);
   env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(version_str, c);
}
std::cout << version_std_str << std::endl
```

Outputs:
`1.0`